# SQL - how to serve the "AS" value for an argument

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have two tables;

`course` that has columns `id, description, units,` and `price_per_unit.`

`student` that has columns `id, name,` and `course_id.`

I want to `SELECT` the student with the highest total tuition fee (units * price_per_unit)

I tried this `SELECT STATEMENT;`

```
SELECT student.name, 
       course.description, 
       course.units * course.price_per_unit AS "total_tuition_fee" 
FROM student 
LEFT JOIN course 
ON course.total_tuition_fee = (SELECT MAX(course.total_tuition_fee) FROM course);
```

But it doesn't work, I used `AS` for my `course.units * course.price_per_unit` and named it as `total_tuition_fee` but I can't put it in my `ON` argument.

Comment: Is course table contain `total_tuition_fee` field?

Comment: nope, there's only `units` and `price_per_unit`. I want to be able to know the highest total without having another column. @DhavalAsodariya

Comment: Standard Mysql doesn't allow reference alias column in condition https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html So I think answer is not possible. You may try another approach like alias select clause before joining

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is a bit messed up. First you need to match the join right and then order by tuition fees descending.

```
SELECT student.name, 
   course.description, 
   course.units * course.price_per_unit AS "total_tuition_fee" 
FROM student 
INNER JOIN course 
  ON course.id = student.course_id
ORDER BY (course.units * course.price_per_unit) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This will select the student-course combination with the highest total tuition fee. `LIMIT 1` selects the first entry in the table which is sorted by the product of units and price per unit.

> **Note:** This could be slower than usual as the calculation is done
>   twice. So you could create a subselect with all fees and then select
>   the one with the highest fee:

```
SELECT x.student_name, x.course_description, x.total_tuition_fee 
FROM
(SELECT student.name AS student_name, 
   course.description AS course_description, 
   course.units * course.price_per_unit AS "total_tuition_fee" 
FROM student 
INNER JOIN course 
  ON course.id = student.course_id) x
ORDER BY x.total_tuition_fee DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I have thought of this "alternative" and also thought that it's a bad practice, but maybe it isn't an alternative at all then since this will be the only way? xD

Comment: If you refer to the calculation done twice, see my update.

Comment: I'll go with the first one since it would be faster and more effecient. Thank you! :)